# attempting to implement a load more on a listview shows a blank screen

Tags: java, android

I am attempting to implement a load more in a listview belonging to a fragment. From my snippet when I launch the app, a blank screen is shown, but when I comment out the listview load more, there is no blank screen

Here is my complete snippets

```
    lv.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {

        public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {


        }

        public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
                             int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {

            if(firstVisibleItem+visibleItemCount == totalItemCount && totalItemCount!=0)
            {
                if(flag_loading == false)
                {
                    flag_loading = true;
                    new Download(getActivity(), urlAddress, lv).execute();
                }

            }
        }
    });
```

Thanks for assistance to implement a load more as I am not able to figure out why my attempt is showing a blank screen

Comment: add your Download asynchtask in your question

Comment: added. please take a shot

Comment: Please don't use StringBuffer as it was replaced by StringBuilder in 2004.